# Mystery: React + Radium: 2 Phanton Pixels of extra height for no apparent reason

Tags: css, reactjs

I am projecting an image, then inspecting it:

[image]

[image]

The height is 20px. which is correct.

I then inspect the `data-radium` element containing the `img` and to my surprise:

[image]

[image]

The element has "grown" by two pixels in height, despite having no content. In addition, the `data-radium` element has no padding, no margins and nothing I can think of that would inflate the height.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea where those extra 2 pixels can come from? This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can't inspect the code, I'll try to guess: As images are inline by default, any line-height definition is inherited. Setting the image as a block element could work, as setting the line-height to 1.

Comment: Yep. Silly me. it was the `line-height`. setting the display to `block` on the image worked. thanks.